# How do I perform a simple modification of an .ini file in perl?

Tags: perl, ini

I need change a value in a ini file like this **val2 is the one being changed**

**Before**

```
[section1]

var1=val1

var2=val2

var3=va3
```

**After:**

```
[section1]

var1=val1

var2=value

var3=va3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it the best way use the [appropriate distro](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-INI/) for rewriting the `.ini` file. Here is an overview of the API.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::INI::Reader;
use Config::INI::Writer;

my $ini = Config::INI::Reader->read_handle( *DATA );
$ini->{section1}{var2} = 'value';

print Config::INI::Writer->write_string( $ini );


__DATA__

[section1]

var1=val1

var2=val2

var3=va3
```

Answer (score 0):

Find [Config::Std](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Config-Std-0.007/lib/Config/Std.pm) on CPAN.